# Core Data - Can't find model for source store

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I've been using lightweight migrations and have actually 8 versions but I found that if I install the app from the App Store, then update from the current testflight I get this error:
(I've tried to check previous versions and run the app in xcode but any version I choose the error remains)

I'm stuck with this for days, can you guys help me? Thanks!!!

```
    CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application Support/SocialMinas.sqlite"
    CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
    CoreData: sql: pragma recursive_triggers=1
    CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
    CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
    CoreData: annotation: Incompatible version schema for persistent store 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite'.  store metadata = {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
            Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
            Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
            Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
            Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
            Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
            Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
            Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
            Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
            Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
            Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            1
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    } and current model versions = {
        Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
        Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
        Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
        Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
        Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
        Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
        Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
        Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x850ff1cc d7d83ce5 fdc27686 212198d3 ... 2bde851b 6ca48363 };
        Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
        Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
        Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
    }
    CoreData: annotation: (migration)    will attempt automatic schema migration
    CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application Support/SocialMinas.sqlite"
    CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
    CoreData: sql: pragma recursive_triggers=1
    CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode
    CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
    CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
    CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'ACHANGE'
    CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'ATRANSACTIONSTRING'
    CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_MODELCACHE'
    CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_CONTENT FROM Z_MODELCACHE
    CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database.
    2020-06-18 15:42:19.533928-0300 SocialMinas[1936:422621] 6.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
    to ensure proper integration.
    2020-06-18 15:42:19.731594-0300 SocialMinas[1936:422614] 6.14.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60107000 started
    2020-06-18 15:42:20.588647-0300 SocialMinas[1936:422400] [error] error: CoreData: error: (migration) migration failed with error (null)
    CoreData: error: CoreData: error: (migration) migration failed with error (null)
    CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database.
    2020-06-18 15:42:20.599900-0300 SocialMinas[1936:422400] [error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite options:{
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    } ... returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(134130) with userInfo dictionary {
        URL = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite";
        metadata =     {
            NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
            NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
                Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
                Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
                Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
                Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
                Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
                Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
                Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
                Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
                Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
                Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
                Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
            };
            NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
            NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
            NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
                1
            );
            NSStoreType = SQLite;
            NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
            "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
        };
        reason = "Can't find model for source store";
    }
    CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite options:{
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    } ... returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(134130) with userInfo dictionary {
        URL = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite";
        metadata =     {
            NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
            NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
                Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
                Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
                Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
                Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
                Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
                Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
                Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
                Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
                Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
                Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
                Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
            };
            NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
            NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
            NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
                1
            );
            NSStoreType = SQLite;
            NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
            "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
        };
        reason = "Can't find model for source store";
    }
    CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
        Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
        Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
        Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
        Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
        Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
        Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
        Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
        Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x850ff1cc d7d83ce5 fdc27686 212198d3 ... 2bde851b 6ca48363 };
        Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
        Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
        Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
    }
    CoreData: annotation: : Attempting recovery from error encountered during addPersistentStore: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed object model." UserInfo={URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite, metadata={
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
            Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
            Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
            Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
            Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
            Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
            Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
            Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
            Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
            Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
            Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            1
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, reason=Can't find model for source store}

    Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed object model." UserInfo={URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite, metadata={
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
            Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
            Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
            Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
            Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
            Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
            Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
            Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
            Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
            Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
            Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            1
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, reason=Can't find model for source store}, ["metadata": {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
            Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
            Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
            Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
            Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
            Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
            Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
            Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
            Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
            Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
            Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            1
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, "reason": Can't find model for source store, "URL": file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite]: file /Users/bruno/Documents/Projetos/gnfl-mobileIos-master/SocialMinas/AppDelegate.swift, line 257
    2020-06-18 15:42:20.611155-0300 SocialMinas[1936:422400] Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed object model." UserInfo={URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite, metadata={
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
            Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
            Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
            Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
            Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
            Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
            Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
            Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
            Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
            Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
            Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            1
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, reason=Can't find model for source store}, ["metadata": {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 977;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Cemig = {length = 32, bytes = 0xcff104ac a7f9d3ce e4431a38 04a6ae06 ... f7df05b4 d59d7f20 };
            Cidadao = {length = 32, bytes = 0xf33806b8 4498e699 8e360633 2d17973d ... 065f5601 637fe9b2 };
            Condutor = {length = 32, bytes = 0x0f9c884b 69aa4b41 e2ec210c 1cade1ed ... 385e4f22 99ca5062 };
            Copasa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11e8f521 17feb00e 07be0486 30fdb611 ... 2997cd85 b9261dc0 };
            Empresa = {length = 32, bytes = 0x44ce93a3 a5b9139b bd3a55b2 394111fb ... 3bcb5de8 e84b6011 };
            Favorito = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd20447a8 55da7b9b e7a05f81 5cb6a5c1 ... 9ad8ac59 6595032d };
            Menu = {length = 32, bytes = 0xc743bdfe 8618d739 7dd8500b 37cb7bb5 ... 22937f98 b32d5392 };
            Notificacao = {length = 32, bytes = 0x904a369d 70025c1a fa4723c6 d604f5e8 ... 6f04ec0d 7c960c3f };
            Paciente = {length = 32, bytes = 0xba4199d2 02d8e06d 168ba97c e0b7d4a4 ... 6fcb25f6 e827e124 };
            Pessoa = {length = 32, bytes = 0xe6952663 7971a41b e50b21f1 807d51ae ... e86ba0e1 1c97d1e4 };
            Veiculo = {length = 32, bytes = 0x21bda4ef b832ee90 e7f2a685 543e615b ... 3315e2ee ace5d78b };
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest = "fmR2OfjxoKcta925wRxGqCm0yIvkerd5b+2e/adDwyiISAmljO8aOJTf4cmWk+XbpuQA7G2Sni+s+i1Wuqhy/A==";
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            1
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "49825C76-FC4F-46E5-B4DA-170E2F90A8CD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, "reason": Can't find model for source store, "URL": file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C2D1110-861E-4ED6-A76C-9FCAEEE1CDB6/Library/Application%20Support/SocialMinas.sqlite]: file /Users/bruno/Documents/Projetos/gnfl-mobileIos-master/SocialMinas/AppDelegate.swift, line 257
```